# Split a record to multiple rows of record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table as below
Master Table

```
ID      Name
1       Bubble
```

Child Table

```
ID   MasterTableID   StartDate       EndDate       Qty      UnitMeasurement     
1    1                1/2/2019        1/6/2019    1000         sqft
2    1                1/2/2019        1/4/2019    3000         sqft
```

I need to select the record above and show it in 5 rows since 1/2 - 1/6 were 5 months.

```
 Date       Qty      
1/2/2019    200   
1/3/2019    200
1/4/2019    200
1/5/2019    200
1/6/2019    200
```

Second row record to 3 rows record

```
Date       Qty      
1/2/2019    1000   
1/3/2019    1000
1/4/2019    1000
```

I'm using SQL Server.

May I know it is possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achievable using `cte`. since your dateformat is `ddMMyyy`, we need to convert this to `MMddyyy` so we can use `dateadd(month...`

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
  (id int, [StartDate] varchar(30), [EndDate] varchar(30), [Qty] int, [UnitMeasurement] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO #Temp
  (id, [StartDate], [EndDate], [Qty], [UnitMeasurement])
VALUES
  (1, '1/2/2019', '1/6/2019', 1000, 'sqft'),
  (2, '1/2/2019', '1/4/2019', 3000, 'sqft')
;
GO

with cte as
(
    Select  id, cast(convert(varchar
    , convert(datetime, [StartDate], 103), 101) as date) as startdate
        , cast(convert(varchar
    , convert(datetime, [EndDate], 103), 101) as date) as enddate
    , [Qty] 
    , 1 as ctr from #Temp   
    union all
    Select  id, dateadd(month, 1, startdate), enddate, qty, ctr + 1
    From    cte
    Where   startdate < enddate
)
Select t1.id, qty/t2.ct, startdate from cte t1
cross apply (select count(1) ct, id from cte group by id) t2
where t2.id = t1.id

order by t1.id asc
Option  (MaxRecursion 0)

drop table #Temp
```

**output**:

[image]

Comment: If in one to many relationship, I found the calculation will not correct.   If the child table contain 2 row of records, and I run the query; the calculation for second rows of data become wrong.                                                                                                   
ID  MasterID   StartDate   EndDate   Qty                                                                              1   1                1/2/2019    1/5/2019   1000                                                                                  2   1                1/2/2019    1/4/2019   3000

Comment: @BubbleBub, well, you did not specify it on your question, sample data also doesn't have any grouping column

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Recursively + CTE` and filter using `inner join on id`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE T
>   ([ID] int, [MasterTableID] int, [StartDate] datetime, [EndDate] datetime, [Qty] int, [UnitMeasurement] varchar(4))
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO T
>   ([ID], [MasterTableID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [Qty], [UnitMeasurement])
> VALUES
>   (1, 1, '2019-01-02 00:00:00', '2019-01-06 00:00:00', 1000, 'sqft'),
>   (2, 1, '2019-01-02 00:00:00', '2019-01-04 00:00:00', 3000, 'sqft')
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> with cte as (
>   select [EndDate] as [Date],ID,datediff(day,[StartDate], [EndDate]) diff , [Qty] / (datediff(day,[StartDate], [EndDate]) + 1) as qty
>   from T
>   union all
>   select dateadd(day,-1,[Date]) [Date],T1.ID,T2.diff - 1 as diff,T2.qty 
>   from T T1
>   inner join cte T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
>   where diff >0
> )
> select ID,[Date],qty  
> from cte
> order by ID,[Date]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Date                |  qty
> -: | :------------------ | ---:
>  1 | 02/01/2019 00:00:00 |  200
>  1 | 03/01/2019 00:00:00 |  200
>  1 | 04/01/2019 00:00:00 |  200
>  1 | 05/01/2019 00:00:00 |  200
>  1 | 06/01/2019 00:00:00 |  200
>  2 | 02/01/2019 00:00:00 | 1000
>  2 | 03/01/2019 00:00:00 | 1000
>  2 | 04/01/2019 00:00:00 | 1000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ce2d1c9e8dc83052be30af86054e189a)*

Comment: Sorry, my quedtion was wrong,I have edit it.  The table have ID and it is one to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

try like below for generating date

```
 DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '1/2/2019'
  , @EndDate DATE = '1/6/2019'

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, @StartDate)
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
          FROM      sys.columns c
        ) nbrs
WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

or you can use recursion

```
Declare  @FromDate    Date = '1/2/2019',
         @ToDate      Date = '1/6/2019'

;With DateCte (Date) As
(
    Select  @FromDate Union All
    Select  DateAdd(Day, 1, Date)
    From    DateCte
    Where   Date <= @ToDate
)
Select  Date
From    DateCte
Option  (MaxRecursion 0)
```